# How to set up a Low Disk Space alert with the new Azure Monitor agent to trigger when a specific disk drive is low on free space?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

For some time now, I have used the Log Analytics agents (MMA.OMS) to collect perf logs and send email alerts when a VM's free disk space % reached a low number.  I use a custom log search such as this to trigger the alert:

```
Perf
| where CounterValue <= 10
| where InstanceName == "C:" 
| where CounterName == "% Free Space"
```

This worked very well and accomplished exactly what I needed.  However, I recently started seeing this message in my Log Analytics workspace telling me that this feature will no longer be supported by the end of August next year, and I should migrate to the new "Azure Monitor Windows Agent" feature:
[image: Warning about Log Analytics agent being sunsetted]

I tried to set up the new Azure Monitor Windows Agent by creating a Data Collection Rule in the Log Analytics workspace->Agents->Data Collection Rules.  I created a Data Collection Rule with a Performance Counters Data source, collecting the custom performance counter for "\LogicalDisk(_Total)% Free Space".  This *almost* accomplishes what I need it to do.

Now when I query the perf logs, I only get log entries where InstanceName is "_Total" instead of also having log entries with InstanceName for specific drives like "C:".  While this is fine for VMs that only have one disk drive, this is useless for VMs that have multiple disk drives, including VM sizes that include a large temporary disk drive.  I had to change the custom log search to this, in order to get any results:

```
Perf
| where CounterValue <= 10
| where CounterName == "% Free Space"
```

So, with my new Azure Monitor logs, if a VM has a C: drive that is at 10% free space but it also has a D: drive that is at 99% free space, the log entries show the total free space of both drives added together, showing something like 46% total free space.  This does not accomplish my needs of being alerted when a specific drive is running low on space.

Is there any way to set up an alert for low disk space for specific disk drives using the new Azure Monitor/Data Collection Rules?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below query and able to get the results for the low diskspace of VM.

```
Perf  
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" and Computer contains "Rajesh-vm"  
| where CounterValue < 86  
| project TimeGenerated, FreeSpace = (CounterValue/1024)*1024
```

Based on your requirement, you need to change the `percentage or CounterValue` in the query.

Logs for the low disk space
[image]

Alert rule creation

[image]

Alerts

[image]

Alert Email for low disk space.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, this does not address the issue, which is the new Azure Monitor Windows Agent only seems to return "% Free Space" log records with InstanceName="_Total" instead of InstanceName="C:"

The "_Total" records will average out the free disk space of all the drives on the server, which makes them useless for my purposes.  I need to know when any particular drive is low on disk space, so I can address the issue by increasing disk size.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to set-up Low Disk Space Alerts with the new Azure Monitor agent:

1. Go to the Log Analytics Workspace Resource page and click on Logs
2. Run the Following Query (Adjust Val as per monitoring requirements)

   InsightsMetrics | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Tags, Computer
   | where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
   | where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage" and Val < 50
3. Click on New Alert Rule
4. Set the Aggregation Value to Count and Threshold value to 1
5. Save your Alert